# Is every point in $(0,1)$ part of an open set? A rather elementary approach.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On the interval $(0,1)$ on $\Bbb{R}$, we know that if we select any point $p$ on it, we can find an open interval $(a,b)$ containing it, where $a,b\in (0,1)$.

We say this is true for **every** point $\in (0,1)$.

However, the presence of this open interval is contingent on the fact that there are numbers greater than and lesser than $P$, which are the upper and lower bounds for the interval containing $p$.

Say we have a sequence $\langle x_{n}\rangle$ converging to $1$ in $(0,1)$. We know that any $x_{i}$ we select will lie in an open interval. However, can we say the same for **EVERY** $x_{i}$?

I think there is a difference between saying something is true for 
ANY point we may choose in an infinite sequence, and that property being true for EVERY point in that sequence.

I know we can't say there is a point $t\in (0,1)$ such that it is not contained in an open interval $\subset (0,1)$. But I find it difficult to digest that every point can be contained in an open set.

EDIT: I will attempt to make the purpose of the question clearer. I know that for any such point $p$, we can construct a point in $(p,1)$. However, can the same be said for EVERY point in $(0,1)$?

Also, forgive me for my ambiguous wording; I'm NOT trying to say that there exists one particular open set $(a,b)$ such that every $x_{i}$ is contained within it. My questions is **for every $x\in (0,1)$, can there be an open set $(a,b)$ such that $x\in (a,b)$? For each distinct $x$, the open set $(a,b)$ containing it may be different**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. The point $p=0$ lies in $[0,1]$, but there is no open interval contained in $[0,1]$ that contains $p$. Also, every and any are more or less synonymous here.

Comment: Terribly sorry. Wrong choice of brackets. The relevant corrections have been made. Thanks

Comment: Well trivially every point in $(0,1)$ is contained in the open interval $(0,1)$.

I think you may be having a problem to do with the scope of quantifiers:

It is true that for every point we can pick an open neighborhood containing that point. However it is not true that if we pick our open neighborhood it will contain every point.

Comment: @James- I said every point is containe in $(a,b)$, where $a,b\in (0,1)$. $0$ and $1$ do not lie in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why do you think the same interval would apply to $x_1$ would apply to $x_2$ and $x_3$, etc? The point is, there are intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ for each $i$ with this property. Nothing in the statement "for every" of "for any" means that there is one interval $(a,b)$ that applies to some infinite set. This is the heart of my answer below - you are trying to swap the order of "there exists" and "for all."

Comment: Your confusion is your assumption that "for every $x$" and "for each distinct $x$" mean different things. They mean the same thing. You seem to think "for every $x$, there exists $y$,..." to mean "there exists $y$, such that for each distinct $x$,..." That is not what it means, and this is exactly the sort of error I describe in comments and in my answer. Isaac makes the same point in his answer.

Comment: Note, you wrote in your "EDIT" section, "My question is..." But then you don't ask a question, you just make a statement with a question mark, and then a similar statement without a question mark. If you start a sentence, "My question is,..." the rest should be a question, not just a statement ending in a question mark...

Comment: For every two reals, there exists a real in between them. This should be perfectly obvious and shouldn't be at all difficult to digest. (In fact it is difficult to find statements in mathematics that are *less* intuitively obvious than this!) In particular, for every $t$ with $0<t<1$, there exist $a$ and $b$ with $0<a<t$ and $t<b<1$, hence $t\in(a,b)\subset(0,1)$. As Cale notes, we can choose $a$ to be the midpoint between $0$ and $t$, and choose $b$ to be the midpoint between $t$ and $1$.

Answer (score 6):

I think I understand the distinction you are trying to make, but it is not a distinction between "any" and "every". In this context, they mean the same thing. Rather, you are trying to distinguish between "for every point there exists an open set", and "there exists an open set such that for every point". Indeed, these statements are not equivalent, and the latter fails here. The second kind of statement is broadly called a statement about "uniformity", since the choice of open set is uniform, and not dependent on the point taken.

Comment: That was not the purpose of my question. Kindly refer to the "EDIT" portion of the question. I realise I've been very unclear with my words. Thanks.

Comment: It is the point of your question, you just haven't realized it yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_i>0$, then $x_i>\frac{x_i}{2}>0$, and $x_i<\frac{x_i+1}{2}<1$, as a mid point of $x_i$ and 1. So, $x_i \in (\frac{x_i}{2}, \frac{x_i+1}{2})$.